# Understanding proof: field $K$, $f \in K[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial and $0 \neq g \in K[x]$ then $\gcd(f, g) = 1$ or $f$ divides $g$.

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

Suppose we have a field $K$, $f \in K[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial and $0 \neq g \in K[x]$, prove that either $\gcd(f, g) = 1$ or $f$ divides $g$.

Proof:
Because $\gcd(f,g)$ divides $f$ there exists $h\in K[x]$ such that $f=h\cdot\gcd(f,g)$. Because $f$ is irreducible this implies that either $h$ or $\gcd(f,g)$ is a unit. Then either $\gcd(f,g)=1$ or $\gcd(f,g)=uf$ for some unit $u\in K[x]$. Because $\gcd(f,g)$ divides $g$ this shows that either $\gcd(f,g)=1$ or $f$ divides $g$.

I don't understand how $\gcd(f,g) \not =1$ $\implies$ $\gcd(f,g)=uf$ for some unit $u\in K[x]$.

Comment: it is claimed in the proof that either $h$ or $gcd(f,g)$ is a unit. Hence, if $gcd(f,g)$ is not a unit, $h$ must be a unit. Since $f=h \cdot gcd(f,g)$ and $h$ is a unit, there exists another unit $u$ such that $uh=1$ and so $uf=gcd(f,g)$

Comment: @GiulioR a Unit is defined an element of the field F?

Comment: For a general ring, a unit is an invertible element. For the ring of univariate polynomials over a field, it is a simple exercise to show that the only units are the degree zero polynomials, i.e. nonzero elements of the field.

Comment: @GiulioR but gcd is not 1 does not imply gcd is not a unit. I think the proof is invalid.

Comment: Do not delete a question immediately after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to future readers who might find the answer helpful.

Comment: I raised the issue of posting and then deleting questions, and mentioned it was an abuse of the site. In response to that, you went ahead [*and deleted the question*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4565472/how-to-show-p-is-monic)... and then went ahead, and yet again, for at least the third if not fourth time, posted yet another variation of the same thing. And then **you deleted it again**. Are you cheating on your homework and trying to cover your tracks?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a irreducible , this means (by Definition), that wherever $f$ is written as a product of two elements $gh$, one of them must be necessarily a unit.
For example, when K=R, f(x) =x^{2}+1,f is irreducible, So whenever f=gh, we know for sure that g or h is unit (invertible), in the case of the ring $K[X] $, the units are the constant polynomials,so the only way  x^{2}+1 can be written as a product is when one of the factors is a constant.